# Call to a member function getId() on string after login

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3.x

I am accessing a part of the site that requires the user to be logged in. But the system, instead of going to the login, and then to the site I want to access, shows me the error indicating that I am not logged in.

The controller code is as follows:

```
/**
* @Route("/estrategia/titulares", name="estrategia_titulares")
*/
    public function estrategiaTitularesAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $logged = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
        $user = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find($logged->getId());

        if(!$user)
        {
            $messageException = $this->get('translator')->trans('No se ha encontrado el usuario');
            throw $this->createNotFoundException($messageException);
        }
```

The error that appears is in the line of `$user = $em->getRepository`

> Call to a member function getId() on string

How can I do so that the system first asks me to login, and then does redirect me to the page I want to access?

Comment: Symfony version  3.4.6

Comment: Yes, I replied that the error continues.

Comment: In the controller, check if the current user is instanceof UserInterface (I assumed you used UserInterface for implementing login)
if ($this->getUser() instanceof UserInterface) // check the user
Check also if the user is "IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" // if true access else login

Answer (score 2):

Since you are trying to detect if the user is logged in or not, it is entirely possible that **you do not get a user entity at all**.

If a user is not logged in, you won't get a "user object" from the token storage service, and you'll get the error you are getting when trying to access its properties.

Additionally, your user has already been refreshed from the DB by that point (if correctly authenticated), so getting it from Doctrine is redundant and you can avoid it.

The correct way of doing this, assuming that your user class implements `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface`

```
$user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
    // failure mode. Throw exception, return RedirectResponse, or what you prefer.
    // We are dealing with an anonymous, non-authenticated user
}
```

The token (`getToken()`), *could* be `null` as well, so that's something you may want to check.

But, considering your are in a controller, and that the route handled by the controller should be sitting behind one of the firewalls... normally it wouldn't be ever null.

If it were `null`, something else is amiss in your setup and you better catch it pronto.

Comment: Also, there may be no token. Better to use the Security helper. A string as the user usually happens when using multiple firewalls and you are logged in one but "anonymous” in other. Upvote anyway. Just for the sake of clarification.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to keep the code as close as what they were using already. They could also check if the token is null or not, but that's not the issue they were having, and thought to focus on that. I'll edit the answer to mention these things anyway.

Comment: I have made the suggestion and the error still appears on the same line ($user = ...)

$logged = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();                
if ($logged instanceof UserInterface)
{
       $messageException = $this->get('translator')->trans('No se ha encontrado el usuario');
       throw $this->createNotFoundException($messageException);
}
$user = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find($logged->getId());

Comment: @Nicolas See if the fix in the edited answer solves the issue. If not, please see if you can provide your code in a more readable way. Maybe even on pastebin.com. But I can't parse the code in the comment, sorry.

Comment: With your solution, I have managed to get the program into the IF when it is not logged in, but I still cannot get it redirected to the LOGIN FORM.
I have put the line: return new RedirectResponse ($this->router->generate ('app_homepage'));

And the error I get is: "Call to a member function generate () on null".

I hope this time you can read well. Thank you.

Comment: @Nicolas That seems like a different issue, not related to the original one. If, as you say, with the content of this answer you can detect not-logged in users, it seems the issue in the question has been resolved. Maybe you can vote/accept the answer, and ask a different one. (Although it seems you are trying to access `$this->router`, but the property has not been assigned yet).

Comment: No, the problem continues. The complete solution implies that the user redirects to the login website, and then returns to the page where he wanted to access at the beginning.

Answer (score -2):

Above answer is fine except that you have to verify if the getToken() method returns a valid token or NULL. Here the better version:

```
$user = NULL;
$token = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();

if(NULL !== $token) {
    $user = $token->getUser();
}

if($user instanceof UserInterface) {
    // logged in user
}
```

Comment: The "user” may be a string “anonymous”. Ka boom error 500. Your business is dead, your clients are gone.

Comment: Emix your right. $user may be a string so you have to test if it is an object. Ill update my answer. But token may be a NULL in some cases as you can read here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/22513#issuecomment-296738105

Comment: Frank, if you read the comment you are linking, you'll see that the circumstances where the token could be null simply do not apply to this scenario: this is a controller, not an event listener that could be executed "too early on the request", and it's not a CLI command where you do not have auth; and since they are checking if the user is authenticated at all, it follows this route is behind a security firewall. If not, it means the application is misconfigured, and you wouldn't want to run in that state anyway.

Comment: Thanks @yivi  but if i remember well it can also occur on custom error pages and therefore i think it is just better to validate the token as well and in any case wouldn't be wrong to do.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3a8da96b74ead70638f54ef773c3a4e0ac303089/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerTrait.php#L444) is the definitive "better" version. Better yet is to use it, and not rewrite it for the sake of not reinventing the wheel